# system command error when running sencha touch and android commande

Tags: android, command-line, sencha-touch-2

I get this error `'C:\Program' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne` when i run android.bat or sencha touch command to build an android package.

```
-dex:
      [dex] input: C:\Users\nomade\Desktop\senApp\build\app\android\bin\classes
      [dex] input: C:\Users\nomade\Desktop\senApp\build\app\android\libs\cordova-dev.jar
      [dex] Pre-Dexing C:\Users\nomade\Desktop\senApp\build\app\android\libs\cordova-dev.jar -> cordova-dev-e012870bc87dbe5ae117c728c597c4e3.jar
       **[dx] 'C:\Program' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
       [dx] ou externe, un programme ex?cutable ou un fichier de commandes.**
```

I do not know the source of this kind of errors ! is that related to my sdk or my path variable ?

Comment: you probably need to put in quotes your path because it has a space between Program Files.

Comment: thanks for reply, i did but does not work :(